# How can I merge Spotify offline music with my local music files on my phone?

Tags: music-player, spotify

I have tracks saved offline in Spotify. I also have individual MP3 audio tracks that I have manually added to my music folder in my phone (Galaxy S6). However, if I want to shuffle everything then I have to jump between Music app and Spotify app manually. Which is a pain, and a bit dangerous if I'm driving.

What I'd like to do is be able to 'merge' all these tracks together. Whether this is a single playlist of everything, or a way of moving my local music into Spotify app, something like that.

One option i had was to  just re-download the local tracks in Spotify itself, but not all the music I have is found there.

How can I merge all my music from my device into one usable playlist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to merge them to one playlist. However you can sync local files to one playlist. To do that follow the steps below:

> **Note:** This will require that spotify is installed on one of your computers and that your Android device is on the same WI-FI network as your computer.

## Steps

1. On your pc open Spotify, and go to `Edit -> Preferences`.
2. In preferences, look for `Local Files` and check the sources you want to show the local music from. You can directly add sources like **Windows Media Player** and **iTunes library** by simply checking the respective options. Or you can also add a folder with some music when you click on `Add Source...`.
3. All the files you import to **Spotify** can be viewed and played from Local Files section under Collection in the sidebar. If you have to musch music in your local repository, creating playlists from local files would be a great idea for you.
4. Make sure your Android phone is connected to the same WI-FI network and is signed in with the same **Spotify** account as your PC. (Off-topic: for an IPod connect it with a USB cable)
5. If not already done so: Download Spotify for Android: [Spotify Music for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music)
6. Once the desktop application identifies the connected device, it will show you a pop-up asking whether you would like to sync the device with Spotify. Click on the button to open the sync window.
7. Now the app on your phone will sync all the music playlist you created on your computer to your mobile device.

> **Note:** It may take some time till it is finished syncing the music to your device.

## Conclusion

If you followed the steps above correctly, then you now should be able to listen to local files stored on your pc.
I hope this will answer your question. For any questions, just leave a comment below.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the local files to your Spotify app then you can listen to Music which you have downloaded as offline tracks and your local tracks on one app.

Comment: **How** can you add the local files to your Spotify app? That's the part the questioner had trouble with.